# Google CSE returning different results when run from API

Tags: c#, google-api

I am using the C# wrapper [Google-API-for-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/) to query a custom search engine so that only results for that site are returned. The problem is that the results differ from the CSE page and the API results.

This is the code I am using:

```
GwebSearchClient Client = new GwebSearchClient(@"http://www.eatout.co.za/");

string keyword = Query;
int count = 1000;
string customSearchId = "XXXXXXXXX";
string customSearchReference = null;
string language = "English";
string safeLevel = "Off";
string duplicateFilter = "On";
string country = "za";                

var Results = Client.Search(keyword, count, customSearchId, customSearchReference, safeLevel, language, duplicateFilter, country);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google uses a zero index for the CurrentPageIndex used when paging. I was seeing page 2 the whole time.